# Can I make my Macbook go to sleep immediately after all Final Cut Pro background tasks finish?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, final-cut-pro, macbook

I've been doing some stabilization processing in Final Cut Pro, and it of course takes a long time. I'm wondering if there's a way to make my computer go to sleep after these tasks finish so the computer isn't on for hours after it finishes (if I leave my computer alone for a few hours).

Or is there another trick people do to make this work?

Comment: I usually run a shell script that checks the CPU usage, and sleeps the computer if it falls below a certain threshold for long enough. It's been ages since I've used macs though, and my bash skills are fading, so I can't supply a pre-made script for you.

Comment: @stib That is a great idea! When I have some time I'll look into creating a script like that. If anyone has any resources/documentation on how to check the CPU usage in bash/ruby let me know...